# Is it possible to set xbox controller rumble using JoyFeedback?

Tags: ros, joy-node, joy, joystick

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I see when I use rxgraph while running the joy_node for an xbox controller that it does not subscribe to JoyFeedback or JoyFeedbackArray. Is there any other way to set the rumble for the xbox controller?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67450/is-it-possible-to-set-xbox-controller-rumble-using-joyfeedback?/) by [kb4722](https://answers.ros.org/users/5428/kb4722/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-07-16

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2013-10-24**:
I'm considering buying a Logitech Rumble Gamepad F510, I'd really like to know if ROS can set the rumble there also (or if rumble works or it from Linux at all).  The p3joy page mentions supporting the JoyFeedbackArray ( http://mirror.umd.edu/roswiki/ps3joy.html?distro=hydro ).

**Comment by [Cyril Jourdan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4040/cyril-jourdan/) on 2015-03-30**:
Did you manage to get the xbox controller rumble working from ROS ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I made this feedback node a while ago (and haven't tried it recently):
https://github.com/lucasw/joy_feedback_ros

It uses a custom message type rather than JoyFeedback.

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2015-06-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0